# can't get abstract classes to wok in python 2.7

Tags: python, abstract-class

Am really new to Python. I have an abstract base class BankAccount with two unimplemented methods: deposit and withdraw.

I created two sub-classes SavingsAccount and CurrentAccount. The two sub-classes are meant to provide implementation for the methods: deposit and withdraw inherited from the abstract class.

It works quite well on my machine but I keep getting this error:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

on the online platform where its meant to be rendered.

Here's my code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BankAccount:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):pass
    @abstractmethod
    def deposit(self, amount):pass
    @abstractmethod
    def withdraw(self, amount):pass

class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 500

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if 0 > amount:
            return "Invalid deposit amount"
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if 0 > amount:
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        elif self.balance - amount  self.balance:
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance


class CurrentAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if 0 > amount:
            return "Invalid deposit amount"
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if 0 > amount:
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        elif amount > self.balance:
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance
```

**Updated : Full Error log**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/nose2/bin/nose2", line 8, in 
    discover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/main.py", line 300, in discover
    return main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    super(PluggableTestProgram, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/main.py", line 133, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/main.py", line 258, in createTests
    self.testNames, self.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/loader.py", line 67, in loadTestsFromNames
    for name in event.names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/loader.py", line 82, in loadTestsFromName
    result = self.session.hooks.loadTestsFromName(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/events.py", line 224, in __call__
    result = getattr(plugin, self.method)(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/plugins/loader/testclasses.py", line 119, in loadTestsFromName
    result = util.test_from_name(name, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/util.py", line 106, in test_from_name
    parent, obj = object_from_name(name, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose2-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/nose2/util.py", line 117, in object_from_name
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/57d7029af597c64100ba88a5-57bc46aae713b01900df735e-test.py", line 4, in 
    from tmp.andelabs_57d7029af597c64100ba88a5_57bc46aae713b01900df735e import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/Applications/andelabs-server/tmp/andelabs_57d7029af597c64100ba88a5_57bc46aae713b01900df735e.py", line 1
    from abc _import_ ABCMeta, abstractmethod
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you post what you're trying to import as well?

Comment: Could you provide the full error message in a code block please? It's easier to read/understand that way

Comment: see line 24: `elif self.balance - amount  self.balance:` in `SavingsAccount.withdraw` method

Comment: it it's Linux then maybe it doesn't know that it is python code and threat it as Bash script. You have to add `shebang` in first line (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) to inform system what languge you use - Linux doesn't care of file extensions `.py`

Comment: Thanks. I just posted the full error log now.